# show JSON response from api in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, api, httparty

I am trying to get a response from the movie db using its default response, using the movies id http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/. Haven’t done this before so lots of mistakes im sure.

So I'm using the gems httparty and json and have setup everything like so

controller

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

class MainController < ApplicationController

 def index

 @response = HTTParty.get("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key="api_key")
 JSON.parse(response)
 end
 end
```

and my view

```
<%= @response %>
```

just wanted to see what was returned.

I get the error can't convert ActionDispatch::Response into String

I was wondering if someone could offer some advice or some resources to look at to learn how do do this, and maybe some different methods to display the info returned.

I know that a hash is a collection of key/values but lack the knowledge to extract that data

Thank you

Comment: As far as advice for resources to look at, the debugger and console are always quite helpful.  You can just drop a "debugger" statement into your controller or view and see what you have.   You'll need   gem "debugger" in your gemfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is actually your controller, not your view.

```
JSON.parse(response)
```

should be

```
JSON.parse(@response)
```

You probably want in your view:

```
<%= @response.body %>
```

Comment: Does this work from the console?  puts HTTParty.get('http://www.google.com').response.body

Comment: in answer to the above the output is  uninitialized constant HTTParty

Comment: The URL in the get above should be prefixed with HTTP:// not sure where that went.  Did you just install HTTParty?  Maybe you need to restart the console.

Comment: my mistake with google call, forgot to require httparty first, and now i get a response in the console, though still not working in main view

Comment: so now i used puts HTTParty.get(movieurl) and get this returned  {"status_code"=>19, "status_message"=>"Invalid accept header"}

Comment: all solved now, wasn't passing the header correctly for httparty.